# redirecting requests to my domain

Tags: asp.net, dns, azure-web-app-service

we published our asp.net website to a domain www.domainname.com.

we have to redirect users to our website if they are trying to open www.domainname.co.Uk or www.domainname.net.

how can I achieve that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do as Enes days after checking the domain in your request.

That is, search the string returned by HttpContext.Current.Request.Url to see if the domain you are wanting is here, then redirect where ou want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a asp.net file and `Response.Redirect("http://www.domainname.com");` to page_load or [look here](http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/domain+names/domain+redirects/)